# C# MVC4で複数のViewData.ModelをView に渡す方法

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

複数のModelを利用してViewを表示した場合、どのように受け渡すのでしょうか？

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        using (var context = new testDBEntities())
        {
            //一つ目のModel
            ViewData.Model = (from u in context.test1data
                              orderby u.startTime ascending
                              select u).Take(5).ToList();
        }

        using (var context = new testDBEntities())
        {
            //二つ目のModel
            ViewData.Model = (from u in context.test2data
                              orderby u.startTime ascending
                              select u).Take(5).ToList();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

index.cshtml

//一つ目のModelをループで表示
@foreach (var s in ViewData.Model)
{
    @s.itemName
}
//二つ目のModelをループで表示
@foreach (var s in ViewData.Model)
{
    @s.itemName2
}

Answer (score 4):

2つのモデルを保持する型をモデルとしてください。

```
// 変数model1, model2;があるとする

using (var context = new testDBEntities())
{
    //一つ目のModel
    model1 = (from u in context.test1data
                      orderby u.startTime ascending
                      select u).Take(5).ToList();
}

using (var context = new testDBEntities())
{
    //二つ目のModel
    model2 = (from u in context.test2data
                      orderby u.startTime ascending
                      select u).Take(5).ToList();
}

ViewData.Model = new { Model1 = model1, Model2 = model2 };

return View();
```